# Path of dependency in setup.py

Tags: python, dependencies, pip

I'm writing a `setup.py` file for a project which so far relied on `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

One of the dependencies belongs to another (git) repository, which is loaded as git submodule: `git clone --recursive` of my projects creates a subtree `X` with the dependency from another repo.

The `requirements.txt` file had an entry for it, which was simply

```
./X
```

And it worked just fine.

I cannot do the same with my `setup.py` by placing the relative path into the `install_requires` list.

I've noticed there are two additional keys for the `setuptools.setup` function:

- `download_url`
- `dependency_links` (mentioned [here](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dependencies.html))

From the documentation however it is not clear how those should be assigned in order for pip to find the submodules.

Can this be done?

### Edit:

I kind of resolved as follows:

```
$ cat requirements.txt
./X
.
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

…namely by requiring the submodule `X` to be installed just before **this** project `.`. It is not super-clean, but it just works. I believe this is not the correct way of doing it, but it gives the idea on what is my goal here.

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/289 and the linked discussions?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, actually my problem is not about cloning with `--recursive`, but about `pip install`ing recursively.